# check if name == keyword

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

So i have a json here and im trying to search for name

I am trying to read through the whole json, and only match to name. But im not sure how to go about that.

I parsed the json below into a variable called jsondata

and created this loop here to read it.

```
jsondata.each do |links|
  puts links
end
```

But how can i go about only reading the name field and matching it to a string? Lets say im looking looking for the word leo.

{"files":`[{"name":"github.jpeg","size":10852,"deleteType":"DELETE","deleteUrl":"http://gifs.meow.me/github.jpeg","url":"http://gifs.meow.me/github.jpeg"},{"name":"leo.jpg","size":51678,"deleteType":"DELETE","deleteUrl":"http://gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg","url":"http://gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg"},{"name":"leo2.jpg","size":41407,"deleteType":"DELETE","deleteUrl":"http://gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg","url":"http://gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg"}]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search each string under the key of "name" for the needle you're looking for using `String#include?` or `String#index`.  The `Enumerable` method `select` would be a good choice for selecting only the hashes that contain the data you're looking for:

```
jsondata["files"].select{|h| h["name"].include? "leo" }
```

This presumes you have parsed the json data into a Ruby hash:

```
jsondata = {"files"=>[
  {"name"=>"github.jpeg",
   "size"=>10852,
   "deleteType"=>"DELETE",
   "deleteUrl"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/github.jpeg",
   "url"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/github.jpeg"},
  {"name"=>"leo.jpg",
   "size"=>51678,
   "deleteType"=>"DELETE",
   "deleteUrl"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg",
   "url"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg"},
  {"name"=>"leo2.jpg",
   "size"=>41407,
   "deleteType"=>"DELETE",
   "deleteUrl"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg",
   "url"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg"}
]}

jsondata["files"].select{|h| h["name"].include? "leo" }
#  => [{"name"=>"leo.jpg", "size"=>51678, "deleteType"=>"DELETE", "deleteUrl"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg", "url"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg"}, {"name"=>"leo2.jpg", "size"=>41407, "deleteType"=>"DELETE", "deleteUrl"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg", "url"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg"}]
```

Comment: And how can i pull the url out if it finds something that contains leo?

Comment: If you want all relevant urls, you could use `map` on the resultant `hash`: `jsondata["files"].select{|h| h["name"].include? "leo" }.map{|h| h["url"] }`

Answer (score 1):

```
jsondata.each do |link|
  if link.name =~ /leo/
    # do something
  end
end
```

or

```
jsondata.each do |link|
  if link.name.include? 'leo'
    # do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `jsondata` as defined by @Cam, you can do the following.

```
jsondata["files"].each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
  h[g["name"]]=g["url"] if g["name"] =~ /\Aleo/ }
  #=> {"leo.jpg"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo.jpg",
  #    "leo2.jpg"=>"http=>//gifs.meow.me/leo2.jpg"}
```